# unable to sync, run or test simple app android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

After some years of working with Eclipse, I decided to update myself and installing and using Android Studio on my new PC.
First of all, after installing JDK and JRE, I downloaded Android Studio 3.6 from Google Android Official website.
after installing android studio and SDK, I decided to run the Android studio start wizard for generating a simple uni-Activity project to test it and here the problems started.
I got errors by below texts:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.
org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom'.
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I googled for error and no way resolved the problem.
so what's your idea about this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It may be a DNS problem, as your errors begin with "Could not resolve".. So when certain sites cannot be resolved by DNS, that leads to the other errors of not being able to get resources.

Comment: OMG errors increased more than before and they are very strange for me: https://imgur.com/CxJybZs